# R Writing Excel Document

Tags: html, r, excel, saving-data

My question is whether or not anybody knows of a better way to do what I'm already doing. I'm creating a report as a list, and trying to render it both in HTML and Excel.

I'm developing a shiny app that generates reports for Qualtrics surveys.

[image: results tables example]

The results table is a list of HTML strings that I paste together and display in a shinydashboard. Here's a [dput of the example results tables](http://pastebin.com/raw/nqND4C8a).

Here's how I'm creating the html results tables list -- [the html_tabelize() function](http://pastebin.com/embed_js/gFf7zD15) in my package. Here's a [dput of the example input](http://pastebin.com/raw/rDgYKPh4).

In the shiny server.R file the way I create the Excel file is with the following code:

```
output$downloadResults <- downloadHandler(
  filename = 'tables.xls',
  content = function(file) {
    write(html_tabelize(main()[['blocks']]), file)
  }
)
```

To summarize: I get the blocks, I run html_tabelize on them, and then I write the HTML output to a file called "tables.xls". When I open that file, because Excel can render HTML, it renders something like this:

[image: excel render of results tables]

My concern and problem with what I'm doing are two-fold:

1. If I were writing an Excel document instead of simply rendering HTML in Excel, then I could perhaps get a better formatted document. I'd like that.
2. When you download the results tables xls file and try to open it, you get a warning from Excel. I don't want the users of my app to see this warning, because it's distracting and could worry them about something that isn't really a concern.

[image: warning from Excel]

I know that [options exist for writing Excel files in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WriteXLS/WriteXLS.pdf), but so far what I've seen indicates that their input must be either a data frame, or a list of data frames. The list I am rendering from has different types of components, like the question text, as well as data frames of results. Originally I was using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/), but pandoc, even when run from R, is a system binary, and it's difficult to list as a dependency (and if I can't list it as a dependency, it's tough to make sure it's installed for the users of my app). Additionally, I found out pandoc doesn't even convert to "real" Excel -- it also just saves HTML in a .xls file. Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I can improve this part of my app?

Comment: [XLConnect](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/XLConnect.pdf) has pretty extensive writing functions that could probably do what you want.

Comment: you're right! that looks like it'll do the job, thank you!